# How to find Next Sunday in different Timezone (EST & IST)

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone, nsdate

I have to find next Sunday date (NSDate) from device's current date.

I have used below logic:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:self];
NSUInteger weekdayToday = [components weekday];

NSInteger daysToMonday = (8 - weekdayToday) % 7;

NSDate *weekEndPrev = [self dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToMonday];
```

Here, in EST if time is near to 11 PM, I'm getting Monday as Weekend.

Let me know feasible solution. I have tried many options. Nothings works with 2 different timezones.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try with this line after **NSCalendar** alloc `calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];`

Comment: "Here, in EST if time is near to 11 PM, I'm getting Monday as Weekend." How are you displaying your value to see its Monday? 11PM EST Sunday is 4AM UTC Monday and `NSLog` dumps the UTC time, an `NSDateFormatter` with its `timeZone` property set to EST will show Sunday.

Comment: After conversion I need to pass string from date.. that returns Monday..

Answer (score 0):

You need just to get the number of days you need and then just add them to your current date:

```
    NSCalendar * calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDate * newDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:value toDate:date options:0];
```

where `value` - is the number of days to add

Comment: How to find "value"?

Comment: @DimpleShah try as you are doing

Comment: @DimpleShah the problem was in your `dateByAddingTimeInterval` as you are adding the `interval` and when you are getting time in one-time zone and adding in another time zone you are getting the wrong result. When you add `day` you are ignoring time, so it does not effect on your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Find current week Sunday Date first then add 7 days using NSDateComponents.

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:today];
NSDateComponents *componentsToSubtract = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsToSubtract setDay:(0 - ([weekdayComponents weekday] - 1))];
NSDate *sudayCurWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToSubtract toDate:today options:0];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:7];
NSDate *nextSunday = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:sudayCurWeek options:0];
NSLog(@"%@",nextSunday);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without any math, which is best left to `NSCalendar` as it handles daylight savings etc. First you need a calendar with the correct time zone. For example for IST:

```
NSCalendar *gc = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
gc.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"IST"];
```

Then you can use `nextDateAfterDate:matchingUnit:value:options:` to find the start of the next Sunday after a given time. For example:

```
NSDate *start = ... // the time you wish to start from
NSDate *nextSunday =
    [gc nextDateAfterDate:start
                 matching:UnitNSCalendarUnitWeekday // match based on weekday number
                    value:1                         // Sunday = weekday 1
                  options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime   // read the docs!
    ];
```

The returned date, `nextSunday`, will be the next Sunday at 00:00 in the timezone of the calendar, `gc`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got solution..

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] componentsInTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"] fromDate:[NSDate date]]; // Pass date for which you want to find next Sunday
NSUInteger weekdayToday = [components weekday];
NSInteger daysToMonday = (8 - weekdayToday) % 7;
NSDate *weekEndPrev = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToMonday];
```